# Convert CSV headers & values to maps and rest to list of maps Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have CSV file as

```
revenue,currency,date,random1,random2,random3
1.234,eur,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,usd,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,eur,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,bng,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,eur,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,eur,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,jpy,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,cny,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,chf,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,eur,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
1.234,eur,2020-05-19,"random","random","random"
```

the above one is just a sample but it can have many unexpected columns the first 3 are constant and the same (headers) in every CSV.

I am trying to get these first 3 columns to a map and the rest columns to a list of maps.

I have tried this so far,

```
"csvs/download.csv"
|> File.stream!()
|> NimbleCSV.RFC4180.parse_stream(skip_headers: false)
|> Stream.transform([], fn r, acc ->
  {[Enum.zip(acc, r) |> Enum.into(%{})], acc}
end)
|> Enum.to_list()
```

This gives me, just a list of empty maps,

```
[%{}, %{}, %{}, %{}, %{}, %{}, %{}, %{}, %{}, %{}, %{}, %{}]
```

My plan was to convert it like this and then take the first 3 in a list and rest into another list. But the first part is not working.

any help would be wonderful. the expected results after parsing would be

```
    [
      %{revenue: revenue, currency: currency, date: date, rest: [%{anyname: any_data, anyname: any_data}]},
      %{revenue: revenue, currency: currency, date: date, rest: [%{anyname: any_data, anyname: any_data}]}
      ....
]
```

This is what I did for solution:

```
data = NimbleCSV.RFC4180.parse_string(File.read("path_to_csv.csv"), skip_headers: false)
known_headers = ~w(revenue currency date)
[headers | content] = data
content
|> Enum.map(fn row ->
  headers |> Enum.zip(row) |> Map.new |> Map.split(known_headers)
end)
```

to get the expected results, But I know there could be a better solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `acc` is an empty list, and zipping to an empty list results in the empty list on each step. You should explicitly initiate `acc` if it’s empty.

```elixir
"csvs/download.csv"
|> File.stream!()
|> NimbleCSV.RFC4180.parse_stream(skip_headers: false)
|> Stream.transform([], fn 
  r, [] -> {[], r}  # ⇐ THIS
  r, acc -> {[acc |> Enum.zip(r) |> Map.new()], acc}
end)
|> Enum.to_list()
```

---

To regroup the outcome, tackle with `[acc |> Enum.zip(r) |> Map.new()]` part. E. g. to split the map as in the question:

```elixir
  r, acc ->
    {result, others} =
      acc
      |> Enum.zip(r)
      |> Map.new()
      |> Map.split(~w|revenue currency date|)
     {[Map.put(result, :others, others)], acc}
```

Comment: Hey Aleksei, can you guide to get the expected output mentioned above in question? maybe?

Comment: There are no rules shared, so I cannot suggest anything, but it’s all-around `acc |> Enum.zip(r) |> Map.new()`.

Comment: I updated the question with my solution, and what I was trying to do.

I have a CSV file, which has 3 columns to be the same every time but all other columns can be a random one. I am just trying to get a list of those maps where

an item would look like this: %{"currency" => "eur", "date" => "2020-05-19", "revenue" => "1.234", others: [%{"random1" => "random", "random2" => "random", "random3" => "random"}]}